# MacOS Android Studio 3.6.3 new created XMLs are red (autocompletion)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

Before I start an Android Studio application, everything is OK, but the problem happens after the application starts the first time. When I create a new XML file (layout/main_fragment.xml for example), it is not found in R.layout.main_fragment after generating that is no autocompletion suggestions for recently created ones. I tried to build, rebuild, delete Build folders and only restarting of Studio helps, but it is a time wasting to restart after every application launch.

P.S. The app always launches but it is still highlighted red and there are no generated classes in "generated" folders at all.

Comment: Are you invalidating the cache when you restart? And cleaning the project before rebuild?

Comment: @ViniciusVeríssimo 1) Yes, I do, but even without cache invalidation it gets fixed after restart. 2) Yes, I do, I tried with cleaning and without it and tried to delete Build folders by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check import line that import R in your file
It must be something like : import packageName.R